# Change size of dingbat

Tags: fontsize, size

The dingbat called "OrnamentDiamondSolid" is too big. I tried putting footnotesize on it, which helped a little. How can I make it yet smaller?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{bbding}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\footnotesize{\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\scalebox{0.25}{\OrnamentDiamondSolid}`?

Comment: `\footnotesize` does not take arguments, look at Clara's answer to see how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{bbding}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{description}
\item[\OrnamentDiamondSolid] Text
\item[{\small\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\footnotesize\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\scriptsize\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\tiny\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\fontsize{5pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\fontsize{4pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\fontsize{3pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\fontsize{2pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\item[{\fontsize{1pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont\OrnamentDiamondSolid}] Text
\end{description}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]